# MYSQL query to get array list with each row having different children

Tags: mysql, mysql-json, json-arrayagg

Lets say we have three tables

**category_level_one**

| id | cat_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Physics |
| 2 | Chemistry |

**category_level_two**

| id | sub_cat_name | cat_l1_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Organic | 2 |
| 2 | Inorganic | 2 |
| 3 | Physical | 2 |
| 4 | Mechanics | 1 |
| 5 | Electricity and Magnetism | 1 |

**category_level_three**

| id | sub_cat_name | cat_l1_id | cat_l2_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Atoms and Molecules | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | Chemical Equilibrium | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | Alcohols | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | Ethers | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | P Block Element | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | Kinematics | 1 | 4 |
| 7 | Work Power and Energy | 1 | 4 |
| 9 | Current Electricity | 1 | 5 |

```
SELECT category_level_two.id, category_level_two.sub_cat_name, 
JSON_OBJECT("id" , category_level_one.id, 'name', category_level_one.cat_name ) AS "categotyOne", 
(select json_arrayagg(JSON_OBJECT(
                                'id', category_level_three.id,
                                'name', category_level_three.sub_sub_cat_name))
                            from category_level_two
                            INNER JOIN category_level_three  
                            ON category_level_three.cat_l2_id = category_level_two.id
                            WHERE category_level_two.id = 1)  as "categotyThree",
FROM category_level_two
JOIN category_level_one 
ON category_level_two.cat_l1_id = category_level_one.id  
WHERE category_level_two.id WHERE = 1
```

It will give data as

| id | name | categotyOne | categotyThree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Organic | { "id" : 1 , "name" : "Chemistry" } | [ {...} , {...}] |

**How can I get the multiple unique rows for category_l2 with each categotyThree list that belongs to that catl2 ?**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('data', JSON_ARRAYAGG(output)) results
FROM (
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
        'name', p2.sub_cat_name, 
        'cat_l2_id', p2.id,
        'cat_l1_id', p1.id,
        'namel1' , p1.cat_name,
        'cat1', JSON_OBJECT("id" , p1.id, 'name', p1.cat_name ), 
        'catl2', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'cat_l2_id', p2.id, 
                'name', p3.sub_sub_cat_name, 
                'cat_l3_id', p3.id
            )
        )
    ) output,
    p1.id as 'cat1',
    p2.id as 'cat2',
    p3.id as 'cat3' 
    FROM category_level_two  p2
    JOIN category_level_three p3
    ON p2.id = p3.cat_l2_id  
    JOIN category_level_one p1
    ON p2.cat_l1_id = p1.id  
    WHERE p2.id IN (2,4)
    GROUP BY p2.id
) x
```